# How to generate the following time series without using a loop?

Tags: r

I want to generate the following time series:

```
n <- 200
y <- numeric(200)
y[1] <- rnorm(1)
for (t in 2:n) {
  y[t] <- cos(t * pi / 30) + 3 * sin(t * pi / 30) + 0.5 * y[t - 1] + rnorm(1)
}
```

Is there any way to genereate this series without a for-loop?

Comment: To my knowledge - not possible.  You need a loop because you have `y[t-1]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some recursive definitions such as this you can use `Reduce` to get calculate your desired value. For example

```
y <- Reduce(function(prev, t) {
  cos(t * pi / 30) + 3 * sin(t * pi / 30) + 0.5 * prev + rnorm(1)
}, 2:n, init=rnorm(1), accumulate = TRUE)
```